# Numpy accessing column of genfromtxt array raises IndexError

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I'm reading tab separated files. I want to infer the type of the columns automatically and then read all members of the first column.

However, the type numpy outputs can vary a lot, depending on the input (single or multi-column) and on the `dtype` parameter used.

Here is a set of test cases

```
multi_col = "a\t1\t2\nb\t3\t4"

a = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(multi_col), delimiter="\t", skip_header=0,
                  dtype=[('f0', '|S16'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8')])
print_properties(a, 'a')
print("first col a['f0'] = " + str(a['f0']) + '\n')

a = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(multi_col), delimiter="\t", skip_header=0, dtype=None)
print_properties(a, 'a')
print("first col a['f0'] = " + str(a['f0']) + '\n')

a = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(multi_col), delimiter="\t", skip_header=0, dtype=str)
print_properties(a, 'a')
print('first col a[:, 0] = ' + str(a[:, 0]) + '\n')

single_col = "a\nb"

b = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(single_col), delimiter="\t", skip_header=0, dtype=[('f0', '|S16')])
print_properties(b, 'b')
print("first col b['f0'] = " + str(b['f0']) + '\n')

b = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(single_col), delimiter="\t", skip_header=0, dtype=None)
print_properties(b, 'b')
print('already a column\n')

b = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(single_col), delimiter="\t", skip_header=0, dtype=str)
print_properties(b, 'b')
print('already a column\n')

single_val = "a\n"

c = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(single_val), delimiter="\t", skip_header=0, dtype=str)
print_properties(c, 'c')
print('single value\n')
```

I can't find a way to access the first column in a uniform way. Different operators are needed for different cases.

If I use `col0 = a[:, 0]` in the first 2 cases, I get this error

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

On the other side, if I use `col0 = a['f0']`, that gives an error in the third case

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Is there a uniform way to access the first column without typecasting?

Comment: For each of those cases, print the `dtype` and `shape`.  If the `dtype` has field names like `f0` use that to index 'columns'.  If it is a 2d array, use a number to index columns.  If those terms are confusing read the docs on `dtype` and `structured arrays`.

Comment: The confusing part is that default names `f0, f1, ...` are assigned if there's more than one column, but no default name `f0` is assigned if there's only a single column in the file. That makes things a little inconvenient.

Comment: `numpy` tries to make multidimensional arrays with uniform elements.  Failing that, `genfromtxt` goes the structured array route.  That variability is a price for using the convenient `dtype=None` parameter.

Comment: OK, I found a partial workaround, but I still need to distinguish when numpy outputs a uniform 2D array and when it outputs a 1D array. Any idea?

Comment: If `arr.ndim>1` use the numeric index.  Or is `dtype.fields is None`.

Comment: @hpaulj I updated my workaround to work with files containing a single column with a single value, the trick is `arr.ndim <= 1`. I'd like you to post an answer so I can accept it instead of answering my own question. You helped me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that "worked for me".

```
def print_1st_col(arr):
    # access the first column according to the different structures numpy can output
    if arr.dtype.fields is not None:
        print('structured array')
        col = arr['f0']  # structured array
    else:
        if arr.ndim <= 1:
            print('uniform 1D array')
            col = arr  # direct access (single number or uniform 1D array)
        else:
            print('uniform multi-dimensional array')
            col = arr[:, 0]  # uniform multi-dimensional array

    print(str(col) + '\n')
```